# How to demonstrate that this may belong to integers

Tags: abstract-algebra, arithmetic, diophantine-equations

$\sqrt{(3x ^ 4-12x ^ 2)/16}$ How can I demonstrate that this can belong to integers?

Can you show me?  Please!
(Without testing values)

Comment: Can you show it belongs when $x$ is even and not when $x$ is odd!

Comment: Excuse!  I did not understand

Comment: And What is $V$?

Comment: Square root.......

Comment: Start by factoring.

Comment: How about trying an example. $x=1$.

Comment: Can not test values

Comment: How about you just try testing one value to see if your idea is even correct.

Comment: Can you use that in the finite induction? Or something?...

Comment: You're claiming that something belongs to the integers. Have you actually checked, for any values, that your claim is true?

Comment: I'm wanting someone to show me that this equation can belong to the integers.

Comment: For the record, when I wrote my earlier comment, I thought $V$ was an extraneous character, not $\sqrt{}\,;\quad$ (still does not belong when $x$ is odd)

Comment: the first comment above suggests one to consider cases, when $x$ is even and when $x$ is odd. Did you try to follow this suggestion. The case when $x$ is odd is easily disposed of (then you don't even get an integer under the radical). The case when $x$ is even leads you to consider $\sqrt{3(k^2-1)}$. Do you have any thoughts on the latter case, why not try to resolve it?

Comment: @MeuluElisson "I'm wanting someone to show me that this equation can belong to the integers." Yes, but have **you tried** anything? Why *can't* you test values?

Comment: Incidentally, even if you want more than a specific example, you should *always* start by testing some specific values (if possible): it gives you better intuition about what sorts of things you should be trying to prove/disprove in the first place.

Comment: Are you insisting, Meulu, that $x$ be an integer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:**

Besides the trivial solution when $x=0$,

integers
$x=\alpha^n+\alpha^{-n}$, where $\alpha=2+\sqrt3$ and $n$ is an integer, are solutions.